# Comparing Sex Ratios Between Locations

Tags: r, ratio

Feel like this should be a pretty simple test to run but am having a major brain fart courtesy of having the holiday off.

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
location    male    female
loc1        4456     5332
loc2        346      389
loc3        23       52
```

I would like to do two things with it, first I would like to test to see if, across all three locations, the sex ratio differs significantly from 1:1. Second I would like to see if the sex ratio recorded at each location differs significantly from the other locations.

I have been trying to run a g-test in R to first just test if the ratio differs at all from 1:1 significantly (which I assume it does not based on the p value, but I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly based on how my data is structured). However I don't know how to test for differences between locations.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a logistic regression model with estimated marginal means to do the comparisons.

Here is the example in R:

```
library(emmeans)

# Data

male <- c(4456, 346, 23)
female <- c(5332, 389, 52)
loc <- factor(1:3)

# Logistic regression model

mod <- glm(cbind(male, female)~loc, family = "binomial")

# Estimated marginal means

em <- emmeans(mod, "loc")
summary(em, type = "response")

 loc      prob         SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1   0.4552513 0.00503358 Inf 0.4454045 0.4651332
 2   0.4707483 0.01841119 Inf 0.4348777 0.5069236
 3   0.3066667 0.05324437 Inf 0.2130632 0.4194724

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale
```

As you can see, the estimated probabilities and their corresponding (unadjusted) 95%-confidence intervals are calculated. To judge whether a certain proportion is compatible with a 50%-sex ratio, see if 50% is contained in the respective confidence interval. In the example, the confidence intervals for locations 1 and 3 do not include 50%. Therefore, there is some evidence that the sex ratio differs from 50/50 at these locations.

Now let's compare the locations:

```
con <- contrast(em, "pairwise", type = "response")
summary(con, infer = c(TRUE, TRUE))

 contrast odds.ratio        SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
 1 / 2     0.9395687 0.0720033 Inf 0.7851014  1.124427  -0.813  0.6947
 1 / 3     1.8894289 0.4746981 Inf 1.0485894  3.404518   2.533  0.0304
 2 / 3     2.0109534 0.5250472 Inf 1.0905515  3.708154   2.676  0.0204

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log odds ratio scale 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

The comparisons are made on the log-odds scale and are presented as odds ratios. Inspecting the adjusted 95%-confidence intervals and $p$-values, we see that there is some evidence that the locations 1 and 3 and 2 and 3 differ with respect to the sex ratio. There is little evidence, however, that the sex ratio differs between locations 1 and 2.

R also has a built-in function for pairwise comparisons of proportions:

```
male <- c(4456, 346, 23)
female <- c(5332, 389, 52)
tot <- male + female

pairwise.prop.test(male, tot)

    Pairwise comparisons using Pairwise comparison of proportions 

data:  male out of tot 

  1     2    
2 0.438 -    
3 0.028 0.028

P value adjustment method: holm
```

The exact $p$-values differ from those in `emmeans` because the adjustment for multiple comparisons differs: `pairwise.prop.test` uses the Holm-method whereas `eammeans` uses the Tukey-method by default. The conclusions remain the same, though.